# How can I send apikey for authenticaion using Swift in OSX?

Tags: macos, swift, api-key

I am building a Mac App using Swift. Here is my code

```
import Cocoa
import AppKit
import Foundation


class ViewController: NSViewController {


@IBOutlet var Email: NSTextField!

@IBOutlet var Password: NSSecureTextField!

@IBAction func signup(sender: AnyObject) {
    let signup_url = NSURL(string: "https://my_own_domain.com")
    NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().openURL(signup_url!)
}

@IBOutlet var progress: NSProgressIndicator!
@IBAction func Signin(sender: AnyObject) {

    self.progress.hidden = false
    self.progress.startAnimation(self)

    let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    let userPasswordString = "\(Email.stringValue):\(Password.stringValue)"
    let userPasswordData = userPasswordString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let base64EncodedCredential = userPasswordData!.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(nil)
    let authString = "Basic \(base64EncodedCredential)"
    println("\(authString)")
    config.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = ["Authorization" : authString]
    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config)

    var running = false

    let url = NSURL(string: "https://my_own_domain.com/api/v3/auth/token/")
    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!) {
        (let data, let response, let error) in
        if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
            let dataString = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

            self.progress.stopAnimation(self)
            self.progress.hidden = true

            if httpResponse.statusCode == 401 {
                self.progress.hidden = true
                let alertPopup:NSAlert = NSAlert()
                alertPopup.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
                alertPopup.informativeText = "Mistakes happen. Go and Enter correctly now :)"
                alertPopup.messageText = "Please Enter Valid Credentials"
                alertPopup.runModal()
            }
            running = false

            if let dirs = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.AllDomainsMask, true) as? [String] {
                println("\(dirs[0])")
                let path = dirs[0].stringByAppendingPathComponent("user_apikey_details.json")
                let path_file = dirs[0].stringByAppendingPathComponent(path)
                var jsonData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path_file, options: nil, error: nil)
                let folder_path = dirs[0].stringByAppendingPathComponent("/SYNC_FOLDER")

                let filemanager: NSFileManager = NSFileManager()
                let folder = filemanager.createDirectoryAtPath(folder_path, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil, error: nil)
                dataString?.writeToFile(path, atomically: true, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)
                if let file_data = String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil) {
                    println("\User apikey has been saved to file. file data is:  \(file_data)")


                    var string: String = file_data
                    var split = string.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\"", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
                    var split2 = split.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(",", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
                    var splitted_data = split2.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")
                    println("\(splitted_data)")
                    var savestring : NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
                    savestring.setObject(splitted_data[1], forKey: "SavedString")
                    savestring.synchronize()

                }
            }
        }
        running = false
    }

    running = false
    task.resume()

    while running {
        println("Connecting...")
        sleep(1)
    }

}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    progress.hidden = true

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override var representedObject: AnyObject? {
    didSet {
    // Update the view, if already loaded.

    }
}
}
```

Here in the above code, I am authenticating to my api and getting the json data of apikey and storing it in one file. In splitted_data[1], i get only apikey here.

I have a requirement to get data from other url of the same api. For getting the data, now I need to send the apikey for that api. Previously I have done with the chromeapp and I used to sent as `apikey yashwanthbabu.gujarthi@gmail.com:5c9ba3e84ec8ebd1062ddc4e94e5f0c15df8cade`.

In this way i used to send the apikey to GET and POST the data. But in swift I used to do the same but it was not authenticating.

Answer (score 1):

In the same way you can send the apikey for the url.

```
let config1 = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
let apikeystring = "apikey \(self.Email.stringValue):\(splitted_data[1])"
config1.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = ["Authorization" : apikeystring]
let session1 = NSURLSession(configuration: config1)
let url1 = NSURL(string: "https://my_own_domain.com/api/v3/some_thing")
    let task1 = session1.dataTaskWithURL(url1!) {
        (let data1, let response1, let error1) in
             if let httpResponse1 = response1 as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
                let dataStr = NSString(data: data1, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                let mem_path = dirs[0].stringByAppendingPathComponent("mems.json")
                let mem_file = dirs[0].stringByAppendingPathComponent(mem_path)
                dataStr?.writeToFile(mem_path, atomically: true, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)
                if let mem_data = String(contentsOfFile: mem_path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil) {
                println("FILE_DATA\(mem_data)")
   }
}
```

Hope this will definitely work for you.